# How to extract last date of subsequence in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset

I'm struggling for a while with the following dataset:

```
    id   date       var1 var2     
1   7031 2008-12-01  27  1
2   7031 2009-01-05   6  0
3   7031 2009-02-02   0  3
4   7031 2008-11-01   1  4
5   7500 2009-07-11  30  0
6   7500 2009-10-01   8  0
7   7500 2010-01-01   0  0
8   7041 2009-06-20  26  0
9   7041 2009-08-01   0  0
10  0277 2009-01-01   3  0
```

I would like to output for each id the last date with non-zero variables. Time series for these users are of different length. I expect as an output smth like:

```
id   last_date
7031 2009-02-02
7500 2009-10-01
7041 2009-06-20
0277 2009-01-01
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [take out the row with largest date in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186005/take-out-the-row-with-largest-date-in-r)

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean where *both* "var1" and "var2" are equal to zero or whether you mean where *either* "var1" and "var2" are equal to zero.

Comment: @thelatemail, I would say that your linked question is a *near duplicate*, not a duplicate. That question relates more to largest date within itself (they wanted the last date from each year), whereas this is the largest date in relation to a separate grouping variable. Conceptually similar, but might be useful to have both questions here on SO.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - fair enough, I'd say it's an exact duplicate of the concept, but I'm happy either way.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto I meant here that if both variables are equal to zero, this row should be ignored.

Comment: @Anna, that was the assumption I made in my provided answer. Let me know how it works out for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, subset your data, and then use `aggregate()`:

Here's your sample data:

```
x <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text = "
                id   date       var1 var2     
                1   '7031' 2008-12-01  27  1
                2   '7031' 2009-01-05   6  0
                3   '7031' 2009-02-02   0  3
                4   '7031' 2008-11-01   1  4
                5   '7500' 2009-07-11  30  0
                6   '7500' 2009-10-01   8  0
                7   '7500' 2010-01-01   0  0
                8   '7041' 2009-06-20  26  0
                9   '7041' 2009-08-01   0  0
                10  '0277' 2009-01-01   3  0")
```

Make sure that your "date" variable values are represented by actual dates and not characters.

```
x$date <- as.Date(x$date)
```

Subset:

```
x2 <- with(x, x[!(var1 == 0 & var2 == 0), ])
```

Aggregate:

```
aggregate(date ~ id, x2, max)
#     id       date
# 1  277 2009-01-01
# 2 7031 2009-02-02
# 3 7041 2009-06-20
# 4 7500 2009-10-01
```

If you didn't want to create a new object of your subsetted data, you can also use: `aggregate(date ~ id, x[!(x$var1 == 0 & x$var2 == 0), ], max)`

Comment: Alternative: `x2 <- subset(x, var1 != 0 | var2 != 0)`. Which makes the purpose more explicit and is also shorter.

Comment: @MvG, good call, but I've gotten out of the habit of using `subset()`. But your idea can work fine with `[` subsetting. Thanks.